# Comparing Welch and FFT power spectrum density

Tags: fft, python, power-spectral-density

Based on previous answers from the forum, I implemented a function to compute the Power Spectrum of a 1D time series.

```
def pow_spect(x, fs):
    nt = len(x)
    power = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(x, nt))
    ff = np.fft.rfftfreq(nt, 1. / fs)
    power = (power ** 2) / (nt ** 2)
    power *= 2.
    power[:, 0] /= 2.
    if nt % 2 == 0:
        power[:, -1] /= 2. 
    return ff, power
```

I compare the output of this implementation to the estimation of the power spectrum density given by `scipy.welch` :

```
nt = len(x)
ff_welch, pxx = signal.welch(x, fs, window=signal.get_window('boxcar', nt), scaling='spectrum')
```

Eventually, I compute `ff, p = pow_spect(x, fs)` and I compare : `p_db_1 = 10. * np.log10(p)` and `p_db_2 = 10. * np.log10(pxx)` for a given time series `x`. I noticed that all the coefficients of `p_db_1` and `p_db_2` are very close (up 10^(-8)) except for the first one, `p_db_1[0]` and `p_db_2[0]`. Did I make a mistake somewhere ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.signal.welch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) will, by default, detrend the data by subtracting the mean of each segment. This DC level suppression will only affect bin zero of the resulting spectrum. This is very useful since the DC offset can be so much larger than the noise that it wouldn't fit on a reasonably scaled log plot.